# Page with resizable image on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I would like to create simple website with one unusual effect.

Text on page will be centered vertically and there will be one image on the right side of page. The image should be cropped to fit to browser width.

Here's my example image 850x1000px:

[image: image to display on page]

Website for example it should look like this then browser window has size 1350x650:

[image: website example]

As you can see image is cropped (at top, bottom and right)

Here's another example for window size 1920x1080:

[image]

Image is fully visible.

Similiar effect is on website http://rollpark.us/ - image of parking lot is being cropped when window is smaller.

How to achieve that? Can I do it using only css or javascript will be also needed?

Comment: If an answer has solved your problem, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

### Common solution

css

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/900" width="600" height="900">
  </body>
</html>
```

Working example (resize the browser's window to see how the image will scale): https://jsfiddle.net/mattiascaricato/zgzmmxxp/

The image will auto resize to the max width of the browser's window by using `max-width: 100%` and `height: auto`.It will scale down if it has to but will never scale up to be larger than its original size.

### A new solution

Use the new HTML5 tag `<picture>`. It allows you to load an entirely different image depending on viewport height and width. But keep in mind **this is a experimental technology**. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture for more information

Example

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="small-image.jpg" media="(max-width: 768px)">
    <source srcset="default-image.jpg">
    <img srcset="default-image.jpg" alt="Example image">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center; 
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-column {
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 50%;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 50%;  
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.flex-column.right-area { // Added
  -webkit-align-self: stretch;
  align-self: stretch;
}
.image-container {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-column left-area"><span>Your text goes here</span></div>
  <div class="flex-column right-area">
    <div class="image-container" style="background-color:#f00;"></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Edited
Added "align-self: stretch;" property to right column

Edited 
Yes, sure. Forgot to add "height: 100%" to image-container

Comment: it's not working yet. when using "inspect element" in browser it says that image-container has size 944.5 x 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css

```
img{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```